# Static private variables in javascript for own library

Tags: javascript, c++, class, static

I've developed a library to make an easy to use class structure like in C++. I know there are many ways to archive a C++ equivalent behavior in JS, but some of them are really hard to restrict like function redefinition. 
For this I developed ClassBuilder.js.

Currently I can cover most of the behavoir of C++ by encapsulation and defining properties. This includes privacy of members like private, protected and public, virtual functions, privacy of inheritance. Also constructor and destructor calls.

Currently I try to solve one of my last points on the list: Static members. Public static members are easy to solve by using the constructor function as an object an define properties for them in this object.

Private Static members become a little bit more complicated. For my latest derivated class I can use the methode of *Declaring private static member variable in JavaScript: Answer from Barmar* at stackoverflow.com/a/33158134/1789369 (I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links)

But I didn't get a solution for the base classes.
I would like to ask for suggestions.
Even if you think a full restructuring is needed.

Best regards and many thanks.

[ClassBuilder.js documentation](http://moelendoerp.de/classbuilder/?page=documentation)

[Latest ClassBuilder.js files](http://moelendoerp.de/classbuilder/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use const in es6 see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

See also defined getter property (like length in array)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: I've already omitted `let` due to backward compatibility. Thank you for that suggestions.